# Преобразование коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

```
public class PlayerManager {

    private static final Map<String, Player> players = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Player>());

    public synchronized void add(Player player) {
        players.put(player.getName(), player);
    }

    public synchronized void remove(Player player) {
        players.remove(player);
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return Collections.synchronizedList((List<Player>) players.values());
    }

    public synchronized int getOnlinePlayers() {
        return players.size();
    }

    public synchronized Player getPlayer(String player) {
        return players.get(player);
    }

    public void sendPacketToAll(PacketWritable packet) {
        sendPacketToAll(packet, null);
    }

    public void sendPacketToAll(PacketWritable packet, Player exceptPlayer) {
        for (Player player : getPlayers()) {
            if (player != exceptPlayer) {
                player.writePacket(packet);
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        output.append("[Online:" + getOnlinePlayers() + "]");

        boolean first = true;
        output.append("[");

        for (Player player : getPlayers()) {

            if (first) {
                output.append(player.getName());
                first = false;
            } else {
                output.append(", " + player.getName());
            }
        }

        output.append("]");

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

При попытке получить список игроков с помощью метода `getPlayers()` получаю ошибку:

> java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection cannot be cast to java.util.List.

Путем гуглению не пришел к решению вопроса. Подскажите, как исправить.

Comment: Возможно, проблема в коде

    (List<Player>) players.values()

т. к. `Map.values()` возвращает лишь `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой проблемы, возвращайте как экземпляр коллекции. Если нужен список то создайте новый и просто добавьте в него все нужные елементы. Еще мне кажется что нет необходимости делать методы данного класса synchronized. А так же можно просто использовать ConcurrentHashMap для хранения данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Player>(players.values()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код будет работать очень медленно. Если действительно Вам нужны синхронизированные коллекции, то смотрите в сторону пакета concurent.  Там коллекции на все случаи жизни.А синхронайзед - потенциально узкое место кода. Если делать все синхронайзед, то Ваше многопоточное приложение будет проигрывать по скорости тем же операциям, выполняемым в одном потоке.

Если вы настаиваете именно на таком решении, то ваш метод getPlayers() лишен всяческого смысла. Collections.synchronized не возвращает обычную коллекцию, в том числе лист. Она возвращает синхронайзедКоллекцию, а это совсем другой класс. И ваш синхронизированный Мар не возвпращает обычной коллекции. А вы фактически пытаетесь взять коллекцию, привести ее к листу, потом сделать синхронизированный лист, а потом вернуть обычный лист... Ну, согласитесь, бред.

Перепишите метод таким образом

```
public Collection<Player> getPlayers() {
   return Collections.synchronizedCollection(players.values());
}
```

И если вас не устраивает получаемый Collection , то после вызова метода используйте такой код:

```
PlayerManager pm = new PlayerManager();
Collection<Player> players = pm.getPlayers();
List<Player> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(players));
```

Из своего метода получаете Collection и потом из него свой лист.

Но повторяю еще раз, что это плохое решение....